# unable to login after deploying Jhipster (webflux) to Heroku

Tags: jhipster

after deploying a jhipster fresh created app to Heroku the app is successfully deployed however I'm not able to sign in getting the following error

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: **localhost/127.0.0.1:3306** Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused app[web.1]: at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124) app[web.1]: at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:243) app[web.1]:at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:672) app[web.1]: at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:649) app[web.1]: atio.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:529) app[web.1]: at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:465) app[web.1]: at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) app[web.1]: at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) app[web.1]: at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) app[web.1]: at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

***what I tried***
changed src/main/resources/config/application-heroku.yml spring:datasource to use the output from heroku config DATABASE_URL

Comment: Have you subscribed to db add-on? Have you registered a payment method? Is it working when not using webflux? You should not need to manually edit application-heroku.yml , it should refer to placeholders injected by Heroku.

Comment: I'm using  JawsDB MySQL  as add-on, it is free how ever I have a register payed method  and yes it is working when not using webflux

Comment: can you check if jaws sets the needed environment variables? e.g. `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`? Looks like it doe not (anymore?). https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb#java-using-jdbc

Comment: @atomfrede yes the  needed environment variables are created, any way i generated the application with the same properties on a linux machine and it worked fine i still do not know why it didn't work when i used a mac. any way thank you so much